# How to dynamically access values in a variably multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$first = array("a", "b" => array("c", "d" => array("e", "f")), "g", "h" => array("f"));
$second = array("b", "d", "f");
$string = "foobar";
```

Given the above code, how can I set a value in `$first` at the indexes defined in `$second` to the contents of `$string`? Meaning, for this example, it should be `$first["b"]["d"]["f"] = $string;`, but the contents of `$second` and `$first` can be of any length. `$second` will always be one dimensional however. Here's what I had tried, which didn't seem to work as planned:

```
$key = "";
$ptr = $first;
for($i = 0; $i < count($second); $i++)
{
    $ptr &= $ptr[$second[$i]];
    $key = key($ptr);
}
$first[$key] = $string;
```

This will do `$first["f"] = $string;` instead of the proper multidimensional indexes. I had thought that using `key` would find the location within the array including the levels it had already moved down.

How can I access the proper keys dynamically? I could manage this if the number of dimensions were static.

EDIT: Also, I'd like a way to do this which does not use `eval`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that. You have to initialize every level if it does not exist yet. But your actual problems are:

- The array you want to add the value to is in `$ptr`, not in `$first`.
- `$x &= $y` is shorthand for `$x = $x & $y` (bitwise AND). What you want is `x = &$y` (assign by reference).

This should do it:

```
function assign(&$array, $keys, $value) {
    $last_key = array_pop($keys);
    $tmp = &$array;
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if(!isset($tmp[$key]) || !is_array($tmp[$key])) {
            $tmp[$key] = array();
        }
        $tmp = &$tmp[$key];
    }
    $tmp[$last_key] = $value;
    unset($tmp);
}
```

Usage:

```
assign($first, $second, $string);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/VSDcjZ6i)